# IE input field writeable but readonly

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer

I'm using ajax to disable and enable input fields.
When I type something in an textfield, another textfield has to be disabled.
I type sth in, press tab to focus the next textfield, which will be disabled after the ajax request is processed and I am able to write into the disabled input field.

The attribut readonly is set to the input field and when I do not tab into the field, I'm not able to write, but when i type into the first textbox and tab into the next one, i am able to write.

1. Write
2. tab to next textfield
3. onChange is triggered while tabbing
4. textfield is disabled and is set to readOnly while the second
   textfield is still focused
5. I am able to write

Is this a IE bug or do I have to add sth to my javascript function?

```js
element.readOnly = true;
element.addClassName("disabled");
```

Kind regards

Comment: try element.disabled=true

Comment: seems to work, thank you!